# Enumerable.Where(predicate) vs. Enumerable.All(predicate)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What's the difference between:

```
items.Where(i => i.Foo == "bar")
```

and

```
items.All(i => i.Foo == "bar")
```

? Seems like they'd do the exact same thing - is this actually the case, or do they behave differently in some subtle way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** returns a bool value that indicates whether all the elements in question satisfy the condition that is expressed by the predicate.

**[Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** returns a generic IEnumerable collection that contains only the items that satisfy the said condition.

I do not see anything in common between the results that are being returned from those LINQ functions - one is a bool, the other is a collection. Yes, they are similar in syntax, but are used in completely different situations.

A quick example:
Let's say you have an int list:

> List sampleList = new List { 3, 4, 6, 9 };

If you run

```
sampleList.All(v => v % 3 == 0);
```

you will get false because 4 does not satisfy the condition.

If you run

> sampleList.Where(v => v % 3 == 0);

you will receive an **IEnumerable** containing the values that satisfy the condition: 3, 6 and 9/

Comment: Oh, duh, what was I thinking? :) Must have been half asleep when I posted this!

Answer (score 8):

[`Where<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and acts as a filter for your collection:

> **Enumerable.Where Method**
>
> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

In your case, it returns all elements where the `Foo` property equals `"bar"`.

---

[`All<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `bool` and just checks if all elements in your collection satisfies the given predicate:

> **Enumerable.All Method**
>
> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

In your case, it returns `true` when the `Foo` property of all elements equals `"bar"`, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 5):

`items.Where` - filters based on condition and returns a collection of filtered objects.

`items.All` - returns `true` if all objects in the collection satisfy the condition, and `false` otherwise.

Does not look the exact same thing , does it?